# TinyMCE Extensions

Tags: tinymce

What is the difference between MCFileManager and MCImageManager.

I want my user to be able to upload files (pdf, word etc.), images and video.

Do I need to buy both extensions or with the file manager do?

Also do I need to pay for the basic tinymce for editing text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic tinymce does not cost you.

MCFileManager handles all kinds of files, while MCImageManager will allow you to do image-specific actions.